# Seeking birth/baptism record for Noble Hutchinson Fleming who was born in 1827 at Cork, Ireland

Tags: birth-records, baptism-records, ireland, 1820s

I am looking to identify family members of Noble Hutchinson Fleming, born in Cork, Ireland in 1827. The family was Protestant, possibly some sort of evangelicals. His father owned businesses in Cork and Limerick.

Could anyone point me toward searchable church or public records in Ireland that may mention his baptism/birth?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. What exactly is your question?

Comment: Hi, welcome to G&FH.SE!  "Anything" questions are not likely to attract good answers. Specific questions are more likely to get good answers. You can help us help you by telling us a little about what sources you have already looked at, so we can make better suggestions about other things you can try.  You can use the edit link under your question to add more information to your question. The [help] has advice about how to write questions for this site. Start with https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask and https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask.

Comment: To focus your question I think you should ask first about something like “Finding parents of Noble Hutchinson Fleming?” and tell us where you’ve looked for his baptism record.

Comment: There's a fair bit online about the family business or what it sold, so I also think you should concentrate on identifying his family.

Comment: Sometimes we need to go forwards in order to go backwards.  Have you looked for a will? If nieces or nephews are mentioned in the bequests, that gives you clues you can use to look for siblings.

Comment: I think this question is still too broad for focused Q&A.  Have you found Noble's baptism record?  If not, then where have you looked for it?  One way to show that you are also performing your own research, and to entice our volunteers to assist you would be to include details like his marriage record, and the baptism records of his children, which may give evidence/hints for his parents' names.

Comment: @PolyGeo There are now two threads on this subject as I thought this one had been closed down — apologies for the confusion. I have just posted more details on the other thread, which I suppose you can find through my profile. I worked with an Irish genealogist a few years ago who hit some walls. I traveled to Cork where I was able to find information pertaining to the family business but nothing about family members. A baptism record is a grail of sorts but where to begin when there are so many parishes and basic information about his religion that is quite sketchy?

Comment: I think the site will start to make more sense if you start to talk about Q&As rather than threads.  Threads are correct terminology for discussion forums but what we do here is focused Q&A.  You currently have three Q&As (one from 4 years ago) on the site covering similar broad topics and I think all need to be edited to make the single question that you wish to ask in each more clear before they are ready to be re-opened.

Comment: Part of the problem is that a lot of the Ireland records were destroyed in 1922, according to (FamilySearch or MyHeritage or FindMyPast or Ancestry, one of them), including the 1821-31-41-51 censuses. Since he got married in 1852, you might have been able to find him living with his parents in 1851-41-31, which would have given you a good idea of where to look for his father in 1821. But alas, it may be the case that no national records exist anymore and you will have to work with local parishes, which might still have records.

Comment: @shoover I think you should add that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

To search Church of Ireland records you would need a more precise location than just 'Cork' - ideally a parish or town name. Cork could mean Cork city or County Cork, a very large number of parishes. Whereas Catholic records are well covered online on various systems, coverage of Protestant records for Cork city & county is very limited, the main source being the transcripts on RootsIreland which cover just parts of North & East County Cork.

If your line lived in areas not currently covered online then research would most likely require a visit to the Representative Church Body in County Dublin, which hold many of the historic registers, some registers are still held by the parishes, and others have been lost.

Comment: His first marriage was by (civil) registrar in the Wesley Church (Methodist) Limerick city. The church would usually be the Bride's, but if this Fleming line were also Methodist then a 1820s baptism for him would likely be Church of Ireland (Methodism took longer to get started in Ireland)